# Using the & operator in Scss

Tags: html, css, sass

HTML:

```
<div id="carousel" class="slider__container">
  <div class="slider__slide">
    <span>Slide One</span>
  </div>
  <div class="slider__slide--active">
    <span>Slide Two</span>
  </div>
  <div class="slider__slide">
    <span>Slide Three</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
body {
  background-color: #7e57c2;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.slider__container {
  background: red;
  min-height: 250px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.slider__slide {
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;

  &--active {
    opacity: 1; // Why doesn't this inherit the background colour and all other styles?
  }
}
```

I don't know if I'm using the `&` operator the wrong way, but if you look at the styling for `slider__slide` and the `&--active` inside of it. Why doesn't `&--active` not inherit all the other styles defined in `slider__slide`?

You can checkout the codepen [here](https://codepen.io/deangib89/pen/LBjONb?editors=1100)

Answer (score 5):

Because there are two different classes, `.slider__slide` and `.slider__slide--active`.
You have to inherit parent class in this case

```
.slider__slide {
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;

  &--active {
    @extend .slider__slide;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

or another way, you have to use two classes for modifying element:

```
<div class="slider__slide slider__slide--active"
```

Comment: Love the @extend!

Answer (score 2):

This is not how it works. Applying the & operator means, the additional class has to be set as well! It's not a string concatenation.

so this code:

```
.slider__slide {
  &.--active {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

will be converted into this css:

```
.slider__slide.--active {
    color: blue;
}
```

which will apply to this markup code:

```
<!--markup with two classes 'slider__slide' and '--active'-->
<div class="slider__slide --active">
```

but **NOT** this markup code:

```
<!--markup with single class 'slider__slide--active'-->
<div class="slider__slide--active">
```

Also see the [updated pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oMepjd?editors=1100)

Comment: But it _does_ perform a string concatenation! (See the compiled CSS in the OP's codepen) That's exactly the problem, that they end up with to different classes that have no connection on one another.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the full name in active and it will work

```
.slider__slide {
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;

  &.slider__slide--active {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: This will require a user to include both classes on the element, the question is asking for just the active class need to be applied

Comment: Yes, obviously 2 classes if we OP scss

Answer (score 0):

For simple explanation

SCSS

```
.some-class {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;

    &--modified {
        height: 300px;
    }
}
```

This will be analog of SCSS code in CSS

```
.some-class {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
}

.some-class--modified {
    height: 300px;
}
```

If you use only ".some-class--modified" in HTML obviously it will not add "width" from ".some-class" because they are completely different classes.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have applied `background: blue;` on class `.slider__slide` and not on `.slider__slide--active`.

You should be using parent class as well and then the modifier with it

`<div class="slider__slide slider__slide--active">` so it inherits the parent styles as well.

Answer (score 0):

use **&:active** inside the class in which you want to use active.

```
.slider__slide {
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;

  &:active {
    //styles when active
  }

  &:hover{
    // styles when hovered
  }
```

}